# How do I edit protected .ini configuration files

Tags: permissions

I tried to install and run Fakturama a piece of office software.
It installs but it doesn't start.
In a forum they say:

edit `/usr/share/Fakturama/configuration/config.ini`
and insert `org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

(The German original:
editiere die Datei `/usr/share/Fakturama/configuration/config.ini`
und füge die Zieile: `org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` hinzu.)

How to do that?
When I go to that `config.ini` file and open it with scratch I am told I can't edit the file and have to save to a different location?

Answer (score 1):

The area the file resides in requires elevated privileges to be able to modify it.
You can edit is as follows:
From the command line enter:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/Fakturama/configuration/config.ini
```

You will be able to edit and save the file this way.